# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'WebkitAppearance | undefined' in React + TypeScript?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webkit

I see that you do it like `<div style={{WebkitAppearance: SOMETHING}}></div>`, but what is SOMETHING?

```
type PropType = {
  appearance: string;
}

function MyComponent({
  appearance
}: PropType) {
  const style = {
    WebkitAppearance: appearance
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'WebkitAppearance | undefined'
```

How do you set `-webkit-appearance` in React + TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SOMETHING" is the `Property.WebkitAppearance` type from csstype.

---

Instead of `WebkitAppearance`, you probably want to use `appearance`, which is the standard property. Only use `WebkitAppearance` if you are setting it to a [non-standard value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance#non-standard_keywords), like `"attachment"`.

Note that neither of these are assignable to `string` (thus your error); you must use their types defined in the [csstype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype) package:

```
import { Property } from './node_modules/csstype';

type PropType = {
  appearance: Property.WebkitAppearance;
}
```

[Playground examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-zBX0MCLRhMppLZuHZazY29ARmQdnPhSNmHwuH1YsjidzliDfckI9njmSoDC6DJ2lMq2i3OzcjUVordcbdwgA)